# chosen.jquery take an array of values and make them selected

Tags: jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.jquery.js 
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

I have it implemented, and it is working. When the user hits save I save the values to my database. If the user refreshes or comes back to the page, 
I retrieve those values via an array such as ["val1", val2"]
I want to than take those values and have the chosen multi select already have those selected by default, how can I do that? 
I know that I need to update, $("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
But I dont see anything for selecting values.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in another post

```
$('#GroupsShowNext').unbind("click").click(function() {
var index = $("#GroupsViewGroups").prop("selectedIndex");
index += 1;
$('#GroupsViewGroups option').eq(index).attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#GroupsViewGroups').chosen().change();
$("#GroupsViewGroups").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

});